# HTML table data in csv

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, export-to-csv

```
DIV(TABLE(*[TR(response) for response in data],_id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),_class='table-responsive'))
```

using this DIV tag in python controller, I want to download the html table data in csv for which I need to add id.

Please tell me how I can add id in this given line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and code.

Answer (score 1):

You should review [Datatables Package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datatables)

Comment: using web2py can you please tell me how i can add id in DIV which i am using in controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use in template. You should return rendered data. Div is used in template.